# Many instances of ViewModel, how to fix it?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I made ViewModelFactory by [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/ViewModelFactory.java):

```
public class ViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static volatile ViewModelFactory INSTANCE;

    private final Application application;

    public static ViewModelFactory getInstance(Application application) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (ViewModelFactory.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new ViewModelFactory(application);
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private ViewModelFactory(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {

        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel.class)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new MyViewModel(
                    Repository.getInstance(
                            RemoteDataSource.getInstance(WebService.getInstance().getWebServiceApi()),
                            LocalDataSource.getInstance(new AppExecutors(), MyDatabase.getInstance(application).myDao())
                    )
            );
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: " + modelClass.getName());
    }
}
```

In Activity, I create an instance of ViewModel:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(MyViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

Then I want to use MyViewModel in fragments and do as in [this example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing):

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
...

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication())).get(MyViewModel.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
...

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication())).get(MyViewModel.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that when creating fragments, a new instance of MyViewModel is created (I see this in the logs, in the MyViewModel constructor, I display "New MyViewModel Instance Created"). With the opening of each new fragment, I see in the logs "New MyViewModel Instance Created".

Help me please understand how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ViewModelProviders.of(this, ...)`. This means you want an instance of the ViewModel associated with that particular Fragment.

You should use `ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), ...)` in your Fragments if you want the ViewModel instance associated with the Activity.